# @Url.Action add parameter from textbox's content

Tags: html, asp.net, url, textbox, url.action

How to set the textbox's value as a parameter?

E.g. if user inserts "sss" in the textbox, the URL should be like this:

```
http://localhost/myForm1/myAction1?ProcessStatus=3&Condition1=sss&Condition2
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="SearchCondition1" type="text" class="form-control" name="SearchCondition1" >
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input id="SearchCondition2" type="text" class="form-control" name="SearchCondition2" >
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <a href="@Url.Action("myAction1", "myForm1")" >Research Form1</a>
            <a href="@Url.Action("myAction2", "myForm2",new { ProcessStatus=3, Condition1= "sss"  })" >Research Form2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is worked by using onclick.

Html: